# How “if” functions in the context below?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context

THE SOURCE: NEW YORK TIMES

> - “Some of those who try and ban our customs are in essence trying to make Europe more uncomfortable for Jews, because the essence and centrality of our life are our ancient traditions, and **if** our customs are not welcome **nor** are our communities,” Moshe Kantor, the president of the European Jewish Con- gress, wrote in a statement to The New York Times.

Here, in this context, if doesn’t work conditionally.

So how it works here, what meaning is it trying to express, especially with “nor”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfectly idiomatic, to my AmE ear. One would expect **neither** instead of **nor**. "If" there can be understood as "when [the following condition is true]".

It is like a **when...then**  construction.

> If you don't like our customs, [then] you don't like us *either*.
>
> If you don't like our customs, [then] *neither* do you like us.
>
> If you don't like our customs, [then] *nor* do you like us. <sup>marginal, to my ear</sup>

Comment: I don’t know why, sometimes, they don’t put punctuation like you did “, nor” to make the writing more distinct for the reader!

Comment: A comma does help to set off the condition from the conclusion. But the punctuation here is discretionary —a native speaker would recognize the clause pattern without it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a common usage of "**nor**" but by [Definition of nor in US English in Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/nor) "**nor**" *can be used before the second or further of two or more alternatives (the first being introduced by a negative such as “neither” or “not”) to indicate that they are each untrue or each do not happen.*

> **If** our customs are not welcome, **nor** are our communities *(mind the comma usage)*

When the "**if-clause**" is true for "*our customs are not welcome*" the "**nor-clause**" - "*neither are our communities welcome*" is true too.

This is simply an interconnection between a condition and an outcome. If a condition is met an outcome exists else it doesn't. From the point of view of logic you can view it as:

- If (customs are not welcome) then (communities are not welcome too).

The condition here is "*customs aren't welcome*" and the outcome is "*communities aren't welcome*".

Comment: But where is the negative that *introduces* the first alternative? Compare *Neither snow nor rain nor heat nor gloom of night stays these couriers from the swift completion of their appointed rounds.*  or *We have neither the time nor the money to take a month-long vacation in Tahiti.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo With respect to you, I believe that "**are not**" is the first negative. Consider this: "*The jacket is not clean, nor is the shirt.*" - "*If the jacket is not clean, nor is the shirt*". And with "**If..so**": "*The shirt is clean, so is the jacket.*" - "*If the shirt is clean, so it the jacket*".

Comment: I don't think the usage requires that the first alternative be *introduced* by a negative. I'm questioning Oxford here.  *Neither the jacket nor the shirt is clean.*  There, the alternative is introduced by the negative. But maybe they mean something other than "introduced", simply "negated".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'd be glad to know an alternative to your way of thinking. How else do you suppose to introduce "**nor**" in such case? "*If the FBI can't catch him, nor can the Police.*" - how can you rephrase it? - "*If the FBI can't catch him, the Police can't too.*"

Comment: ...the police can't *either* ... or ...neither can the police... as I give in my answer.  That is contemporary idiomatic speech (AmE speech at least).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Consider this: "**The jacket is not clean, nor the shirt.**" - there you have your negatives.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo [Use nor](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-nor) from part 2 explains it.

Comment: Consider: *If we have no funds for pre-K, nor do we have funds for geriatric activities.*    That pattern, which reduces to "We don't have funds for either activity, neither the one involving young children nor the one involving older people) is  decidedly formal, at least to my ear. It is rather different from *Neither the shirt nor the tie was presentable for a job interview.*  **if...nor** is setting up a relationship between the two terms.

Comment: "there you have your negatives." I was only focusing on their choice of **introduces**.

Comment: I understand your concern. I can't disagree with Oxford since really their definition is quite easy to understand. Maybe you're trying to miss something here? Take a shot at Cambridge perhaps? [Neither..nor..not](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo As for your sentence, "*If we have no funds for pre-K, nor do we have funds for geriatric activities.*" is plain clear to mean "*When we have no funds for pre-K, then we have no funds for geriatric activities.*".

Comment: But that when...then paraphrase does not quite capture the meaning.

Comment: What do you think of this one?  *If the shirt was unpresentable, nor was the tie.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Are you rendering the if-clause as something that exists now or will exist in the future? The two clauses are interconnected... if one is true the other is too - if one isn't true, neither is the other.

Comment: The **if** clause there is referring to a present *actuality* but as alleged.  If we accept it as fact that ... which turns into "OK, I'm willing to stipulate that X is true, but so is Y".  We're not disadvantaging the pre-K any more or less than we are the geriatric population.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Not an ordinary combination this is: "*If the shirt was unpresentable, nor was the tie.*" I'm not getting to ask why the tie's presentability is somehow connected to that of the shirt but likely if it somehow is the meaning is "*Neither the shirt, nor the tie were presentable if the shirt wasn't in the first place.*"